# Android get second activity from activity stacks

Tags: android, android-activity, android-package-managers, activity-manager

I have three activity running into application.

```
FirstActivity.java
SecondActivity.java
ThirdActivity.java
```

NOw, I am using SINGLE_TASK so all activities are in stacks.

The placing of activities is like.

```
FirstActivity.java (Top)
SecondActivity.java (below First activity)
ThirdActivity.java (Below Second activity)
```

Now ,I want to check that
**Is my SecondActivity is running or not?**
How can I check that?

I used below things but it return me only **topActivity** from `**RunningInfoClass**`.

```
final ActivityManager activitymgr = (ActivityManager).SystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);


    List<RunningTaskInfo> activ = activitymgr.getRunningTasks(20);
    for (RunningTaskInfo runningTaskInfo : activ) {
        Logger.d(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> " + runningTaskInfo.topActivity.getClassName());



    }
```

I am not saving any activity stacks for now. Do I need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for the answer. I found that there is not any other way except to maintain stack for the activity.
I need to take care pragmatically those activity are active , pause or resume one.